# Gradle Spock test after execution of a task

Tags: plugins, gradle, spock

Hi I want to write a **Spock** test for my **Gradle** plugin to test if a report is being generated after the execution of a task from the plugin, so

```
   private ProjectInternal project
   ...
   public void 'check tasks'(){
        given:
            project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames = ["myTaskName"]
        project.gradle.buildListenerBroadcaster.projectsLoaded(project.gradle)

        when:
            project.plugins.apply(MYPlugin.class)
            project.?????
        then:
        ...
```

But the "then:" section has to check the existance of a file but for this "myTaskName" has to be executed, how to make Ggradle to execute my task? There is no such method
afterExecution ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of test is suitable for testing plugins, but not for testing tasks. Applying a plugin only *configures* tasks, it doesn't *execute* them. In order to execute tasks, you'll have to kick off a "real" build from your test. The recommended way to do this is via the Gradle tooling API.

Comment: So what kind of test to do ? If I do a Junit it will be execute before  the build and before the generating of my report? How can I validate that the generated file is correct?

Comment: A JUnit test that uses the Gradle tooling API to kick off a real build. It takes some effort to make this work. I recommend to have a look at the tooling API samples in the full Gradle distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are prior Gradle 5 you can use project.your_task.execute()